# Any way to create a URL from a byte array?

Tags: java, url, arrays, classloader

Is there any way to create a URL from a byte array? I have a custom class loader which stores all the entries from a JarInputStream in a HashMap storing the entry names with their bytes.  The reason I'm looking to create a URL from a byte array is to satisfy the getResource(String name) method found in ClassLoaders.  I've already accomplished getResourceAsStream(String name) by using a ByteArrayInputStream.

Comment: [java.net.URL docuentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html): one of the constructors is `URL(String spec)`. Then [java.lang.String documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html): one of the constructors is `String(byte[] bytes)`. Create a `String` with your `byte` array and then use the created `String` to create the `URL`

Comment: @BackSlash There is no reason for you not to post that as an answer instead of a comment. YOu get more reputation if it is voted up.

Comment: @tbodt alright, posted

Comment: What does the byte[] contain? The name of the class? If so, why is it not a String? Byte arrays don't work too well as HashMap keys. Or the bytecode itself? In that case, are you looking for a data: URL?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that you use a custom classloader and you want to store/cache the bytes of the content in a hashmap (not a location in byte[] form). Than you have the same question which brought me here. But this is how I was able to solve this:

```
class SomeClassLoader {
    private final Map<String, byte[]> entries = new HashMap<>();

    public URL getResource(String name) {

        try {
            return new URL(null, "bytes:///" + name, new BytesHandler());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

    class BytesHandler extends URLStreamHandler {
        @Override
        protected URLConnection openConnection(URL u) throws IOException {
            return new ByteUrlConnection(u);
        }
    }

    class ByteUrlConnection extends URLConnection {
        public ByteUrlConnection(URL url) {
            super(url);
        }

        @Override
        public void connect() throws IOException {
        }

        @Override
        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(entries.get(this.getURL().getPath().substring(1)));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

[java.net.URL doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html): one of the constructors is `URL(String spec)`.

Then [java.lang.String doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html): one of the constructors is `String(byte[] bytes)`.

Create a `String` with your `byte` array and then use the created `String` to create the `URL`:

```
String urlString = new String(yourByteArray);
URL yourUrl = new URL(urlString);
```

Comment: sorry, this gives a MalformedURLException since they byte[] is contianing the binary data not a binary representation of a location. This is why the OP mentions that the is caching bytes in a classloader.

Comment: @KIC [*Ah seems to work, thank you*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776884/any-way-to-create-a-url-from-a-byte-array/17782177#comment-25928353)

Comment: ok, but why is this an answer not accepted then? And I have the same situation and I have just tried it (even I had this feeling that this will never work out). However, I have provided my own answer how I was able to solve that problem.

Comment: @KIC If you look at the OP's profile, you'll notice that just one question has an accepted answer. And in other questions with answers, there is just a comment, without accepting. This answer worked for the OP, so it means that the byte array didn't contain binary data. It's his case, not everyone's case, and this answer is intended to help this specific case. If you have another scenario, feel free to ask a new question, you'll get better answers.

Comment: This type checks, but I don't think it does what's expected: instead of returning the URL of the resource being retrieved it returns an URL whose path is the String representation of that resource.